# Differential Amplifier with unbalanced differential signal

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, differential, common-mode, differential-amplifier

The circuit topology of figure 1a corresponds to a differential amplifier with resistor load.
Since the signal generator available in lab does not have a differential output, a balanced
differential signal cannot be applied to the amplifier. It could be constructed with the
help of an Opamp, but instead, a differential component is created by using the
schematic shown in figure 1b.

[image]

[image]

**1-** The first question in this guide was to find the value of Rss, such that its current becomes close to 1mA in this branch. And then the final operating point of the amplifier.

In order to find that, this is what I did:

1. To find Rss, since I know the current going trough it, I need to find VS.
   To do that, I equated the problem using the Id formula:

   Id = K(VGS - Vt)^2

   Since **Id = 500uA**, and **VG = 0** because we're working in DC:
   VGS = VG - VS = - VS

   500u = 230u(-VS - 0.7)^2 (=) VS = 0.77V or VS = -2.17V

   We know that for the MOSFET to not operate in cut, VGS > Vt, and that happens when **VS = -2.17V**

   Then I used ohms law to find Rss: Rss = (Vs - (-5))/1m  (=) **Rss = 2830ohm**

   Lastly i found VD : id = (5 - VD)/5k6, since id = 500uA  (=) **VD = 2.2V**

**2-** The second question asks me to determine the differential and common-mode gains, both for the differential output (vo2−vo1) and for a single output at one of the drains (either vo1 or vo2) for figure 1a.

I drew the schematic:

[image]

1. Vo2 = -RD2 x gm.Vi2
2. Vo1 = RD1 x gm.Vi1

- *DIFFERENTIAL MODE GAIN:*

For the differential output **Vo2 - Vo1**:

Vo1 - Vo2 = -gm.RD(Vi1 - Vi2),  **Gain = -gm.RD = -3.79V/V**

For a single output **Vo1:**

Vd = Vi1 - Vi2 ,once Vi1 = -Vi2
Vd = 2Vi1
**Vi1 = Vd/2**

Vo1/(Vi1 - Vi2) = (RD.gm.Vd/2)/Vd = **0.5 gm.Rd = 1.89V/V**

- COMMON MODE GAIN:

Vo1/[(Vin1+Vin2)/2] = **-RD/2RS = 0.98 V/V**

**3-** This third question is what I mostly don't understand. It says: "The fact that in practice the external signal is applied to only one of the ports, as shown in figure 1b, the differential signal applied is not balanced. As stated earlier, it corresponds to an approximation of a differential signal. Explain and estimate the deviation from what you would get if you applied a balanced differential signal."

I understand that the differential signal applied is not balanced, but how do i estimate the deviation if the signal was balanced?